# Laravel/PHP/Carbon parse a date to one and three days from now() to the hour, disregarding minutes and seconds

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Carbon to find dates that are exactly one day and three days prior to a laravel job (to the hour) to send notifications. So for example if the date was `2019-03-10 18:00:03` or `2019-03-10 18:15:34`, I'd like to send a notification tomorrow at `2019-03-07 18:00:00` and another at `2019-03-09 18:00:00`. I'd like to do this in an eloquent query, but not really sure how to "lazy match" by day and hour. If I have an `Appointment` model with a `start_date` timestamp, I know I can do exact matches by day or date, but I want to find matches that disregard the hours/seconds. I was considering something along these lines:

```
$oneDayAppointments = Appointment::whereDay(
    'start_date',
    Carbon::now()->addDay()->day
)->get();
```

...would get me any appointments where the start_date is a day from now. Now how would I hone it to the day and hour. If I were to just use a where clause:

```
$oneDayAppointments = Appointment::where(
    'start_date',
    Carbon::now()->addHours(24)
)->get();
```

...I could get exact matches, but only if the minutes/seconds were a match as well. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to play with the date object before making the query to get the current datetime, but remove the minutes and seconds and add one day to it. Once you have this date, you'll need create a "to" datetime which is that date to the hour + 1 hour - 1 second. Once you have these two datetimes, you use whereBetween in the eloquent query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on my comment above, this should do it

```
$tomorrowStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'));
$tomorrowEnd = $tomorrowStart->copy()->addHour()->subSecond();


//whereBetween('start_date', [$tomorrowStart, $tomorrowEnd])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Do you get what it's doing? Also, be careful if you use timezones on your timestamp.

Comment: Yep, also I have considered that. Thanks!

Comment: also, add an index to your start_date field - otherwise this will result in a sequential scan and will get slower as more records populate. Either create a new migration, or if you can rollback and start again, add to your original migration file for the model: $table->timestamp('start_date')->index();